# Cannot find the websphere server console

Tags: websphere, rad

I am using WebSphere preview server (integrated in IBM RAD), for a JAVA WebService project, and I want to get in the server console, which I am not able to do until now.

The server starts correctly, and when I get in the URL: http://localhost:8080/ the page displayed is the one below:

[image]

Which only contains links to other pages like the information center...

Can anyone help me to get in the server console please ?

Comment: I guess it will be http://localhost:8080/ibm/console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be running the WebSphere Liberty server which does not have an admin console like WebSphere Application Server traditional.  Liberty does have an Admin Center application which you can download [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_ui_setup.html). 
Typically you would not select "WebSphere preview server" instead you would select either a traditional or Liberty server when creating a WebSphere server.